# JavaScript - for loop throws undefined variable. (SSCCE provided)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, a-star

I'm using a A* pathfinding script in a simple JavaScript. I broke my game down to a SSCCE. Anyway, my game is 15 columns across and 10 rows down.

The pathfinding works until you click anywhere on the 5-most-right columns. So if `X` is `11` or greater. You will get this error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '7' of undefined` Where `7` is the `Y` axis of where you clicked.

Here is my `SSCCE`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='graphstar.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var board;
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='astar.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
        // UP to DOWN - 10 Tiles (Y)
        // LEFT to RIGHT - 15 Tiles (X)
        graph = new Graph([
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 1, 13, 1, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        ]);
        //Let's do an example test.
        start = graph.nodes[1][2]; // x - y (15 columns across, 10 rows down)
        end = graph.nodes[12][7]; // x - y (15 columns across, 10 rows down)
        result = astar.search(graph.nodes, start, end);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
Loading... pathfinding. Look in Chrome Console/Firefox Firebug for more information.
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, my game is `jQuery`. Also there is `graphstar.js` and `astar.js`. Don't worry about `astar.js` because it works fine. `graphstar.js` is the where my problem is. `astar.js` is where the `nodes` and such are laid out. `graphstar.js` is where the map is graphed.

See the whole `graphstar.js` here: http://pastebin.com/kx4mw86z (Here is `astar.js`: http://pastebin.com/wtN2iF15)

This is where it's laid out in `graphstar.js`:

```
// Creates a Graph class used in the astar search algorithm.
function Graph(grid) {
    var nodes = [];

    var row, rowLength, len = grid.length;

            for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
             row = grid[x];
             nodes[x] = new Array(15);
                for (y = 0; y <= 15; y++) {
                   nodes[x][y] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[y]); 
                }
            }

    this.input = grid;
    this.nodes = nodes;
}
```

I know that my `X`'s highest is `15` while my `Y`'s highest is 10. But I tried messing around with it.. and I would get errors. Sometimes no errors and the page would get stuck.

Help?

New graphing format:

```
for (y = 0; y <= 10; y++) {

    row = grid[y];
    nodes[y] = new Array(15);

    for (x = 0; x <= 15; x++) {

        console.log("X: " + x + " Y: " + y);
        //console.log("Row: " + row[x]);
        nodes[x][y] = new GraphNode(x, y, row[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `graph.nodes[12][7]` means 12 down, 7 across based on how you've laid out your array. But there is no row 12. Maybe you mean `[7][12]`?

Comment: No because that would mix my Y and X up.

Comment: ... that's my point, you've got them mixed up.

Comment: I see that. I tried to to change them around and I still get the same error. Only this time.. that number is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this all correctly, I think you just have your indexes backwards.

```
graph.nodes[12][7]
```

`graph.nodes[12]` is undefined because there are only 11 elements in `nodes`:

```
for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {

    nodes[x] = new Array(15);  // x only goes up to 10
```

**EDIT:**

This comment says it all:

```
// UP to DOWN - 10 Tiles (Y)
// LEFT to RIGHT - 15 Tiles (X)
```

**This is backwards.**  You do not have 15 x and 10 y, you have 10 x and 15 y.

Comment: Right. I see that, I tried change that 10 to 15... but then I got the same error.

Comment: I don't know what else to do?

Comment: Just changing the loop isn't going to help.  The array you are passing to the constructor only has 11 elements as well.  You are confusing your x and y.

Comment: My constructor has 10 rows down... how will I make it 15? I mean how do I expand the elements without expanding the rows?

Comment: I'm not sure how else to explain it, I updated my answer to try and make it even more clear.  You have your x and y backwards, you are using your array backwards.

Comment: Yes, I know I am graphing out Y with 15 and X with 10... but I tried changing the numbers and it's giving me the same error. :\